# Code is automatically generated by different programs, why is it different?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

This is the same table, but the code is automatically generated by different programs,

1)why is it different?, and the table is the same.

2)which code is better for me to use?.

this is from dbForge Studio for SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE TetsDB_001.dbo.Players (
  [Id] INT IDENTITY
 ,Name NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
 ,TeamInfoKey INT NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Players PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE INDEX IX_Players_TeamInfoKey
ON TetsDB_001.dbo.Players (TeamInfoKey)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE TetsDB_001.dbo.Players
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Players_Teams_TeamInfoKey FOREIGN KEY (TeamInfoKey) REFERENCES dbo.Teams (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

this is from MS visual Studio 2019

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Players] (
    [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [TeamInfoKey] INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Players] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Players_Teams_TeamInfoKey] FOREIGN KEY ([TeamInfoKey]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Teams] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Players_TeamInfoKey]
    ON [dbo].[Players]([TeamInfoKey] ASC);
```

this is from sql server management studio 18

```
USE [TetsDB_001]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Players](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TeamInfoKey] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Players] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Players]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Players_Teams_TeamInfoKey] FOREIGN KEY([TeamInfoKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Teams] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Players] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Players_Teams_TeamInfoKey]
GO
```

Comment: Does it matter? As for why, because that's how the developers of said application/extension programmed their application.

Comment: Automatic generators favor completeness over readability because it's easier to program, which is why you see things like the file group (`ON [PRIMARY]`) being explicitly mentioned by dbForge and SSMS, even though nobody would write that out manually unless different file groups were actually involved. VS 2019 comes closest to emulating what you'd write "naturally". This doesn't necessarily make it "better".

Comment: The only place I see that would prevent me from using dbForge is the IDENTITY specification.  It does not specify the starting value - or increment - and does not specify NOT NULL  (which is required for a PK constraint).